# How to count each value with the same id in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
poll_id|poll_item
------------------
1      | John
1      | John
1      | John
3      | John
1      | Bond
1      | Austin
```

How can I get the count of all values with Poll_id = 1 so I can get

```
John   | 3
Bond   | 1
Austin | 1
```

using sql

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html , I assume you know how to filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` with `where`:

```
select poll_item, count(*)
from t
where poll_id = 1
group by poll_item;
```